# Restriction of $f$ is a diffeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, diffeomorphism

I have a midterm tomorrow and stumbled upon this problem: $M$ is a  compact $m$-manifold and $f:M\times(-1,1) \to M$ is a smooth map such that $f|_{M\times\{0\}}$ is a diffeomorphism. Prove that for some $\epsilon>0$, $f|_{M\times\{t\}}$ is a diffeomorphism for all $|t|<\epsilon.$

I'm not sure how to proceed, but here's my attempt: For $p\in M$ take a chart centered at $p$ $(U,\phi)=(U,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m)$. Since $f|_{M\times\{0\}}$ is a diffeomorphism, the jacobian $(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j})_{1\leq i\leq m, 1\leq j\leq m+1}$ at $0$  is invertible, $(x_{m+1}=t\in(-1,1))$, so there exists neighborhood $U_p\times (-\epsilon_p,\epsilon_p)$ such that the restriction of $f$ on it is a diffeomorphism. Now since $M$ is compact, then we can choose finitely many $U_p$ to cover it, so let $M=\cup_iU_{p_i}.$  Then by choosing a partition of unity $\{\rho_i\}$ subordinate to $\{U_{p_i}\}$, we can express $f=\sum\rho_if|_{U_{p_i}\times \{t\}}$, where $|t|<\epsilon_{p_i}~\forall i$. By letting Let $\epsilon=\min_i(\epsilon_{p_i})$, we arrive at the conclusion.

Comment: Keep going. Write $\epsilon_p$ there.

Comment: @TedShifrin Just edited my answer.

Comment: Isn't it good to carry on?

Comment: @HanceWu I did, my friend!! I just want to know whether there are any flaws in my proof.

Comment: I think the sketch is good. You can try to write it down.

Comment: No partition of unity needed. Just make your finite index set clear.

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you mean that since $f$ is a diffeomorphism on each $U_{p_i}\times(-\epsilon_p,\epsilon_p)$ then it's a diffeomorphism on $M\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$? Also, does my proof work as it stands?

Comment: The partition of unity did nothing. You’re not gluing together locally defined functions. You aren’t yet done. You know the function is an immersion, but you don’t yet know it’s globally bijective.

Comment: @TedShifrin I get why the partition of unity doesn't work, but I'm sorry I don't know how to prove global bijectivity

Comment: You may have to shrink $\epsilon$ further. Do a proof by contradiction.